Querying users's saved items from supabase
I have three tables involved in my supabase database:
properties
  id int8 (pk),
  created_at timestamptz,
  description text,
  price text,
  address text,

profiles
  id uuid (pk),
  updated_at timestamptz,
  username text,
  email text,

saved
  id uuid (pk),
  created_at timestamptz,
  userid uuid (fk) references id from profile,
  propertyid int8 fk) references id from properties


So my 'onLikeButtonTapped' function that inserts or deletes a saved item seems to be working fine and the changes are reflected on the database.
Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool isLiked) async {
  try {
    var userId = supabase.auth.currentUser!.id;

    if (userId == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('User is not logged in!'), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      );
      return !isLiked; // Revert the like status
    }

    if (isLiked) {
      // Unlike the item
      final response = await supabase
          .from('sale_saved')
          .delete()
          .eq('userid', userId) 
          .eq('sale_listing', widget.saleListingId as Object);

      if (response.error == null) {
        setState(() {
          this.isLiked = false;
        });
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Item unliked successfully!'), backgroundColor: Colors.green),
        );
        return false; // Unliked
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to unlike item, please try again.'), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
        );
        return true; // Failed to unlike, revert
      }
    } else {
      // Like the item
      final response = await supabase
          .from('sale_saved')
          .insert({
        'userid': userId, 
        'sale_listing': widget.saleListingId,
      });

      if (response.error == null) {
        setState(() {
          this.isLiked = true;
        });
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Item liked successfully!'), backgroundColor: Colors.green),
        );
        return true; // Liked
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to like item, please try again.'), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
        );
        return false; // Failed to like, revert
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text('Something went wrong, please try again.'), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
    );
    return !isLiked; 
  }
}

my _checkIfLiked() function, however, does not work and always returns the error that is caught.
Future<void> _checkIfLiked() async {
  try {
    var userId = supabase.auth.currentUser!.id;

    if (userId == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('User is not logged in!'), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      );
      return;
    }

    final response = await supabase
        .from('sale_saved')
        .select('*')
        .eq('userid', userId)  
        .eq('sale_listing', widget.saleListingId as Object);

    if (response.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        isLiked = true;
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Error checking if liked: $e');
    }
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text('Something went wrong, please try again.'), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
    );
  }
}

Any insight on what could be wrong with my above function would be great.
